# When and why does $r|m \Rightarrow (p^r - 1)|(p^m-1) \Rightarrow (T^{p^r}-T)|(T^{p^m}- T)$ hold?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I've come across a proof where they use the fact that for $p$ prime, $r, m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r|m$ it holds that $(p^r - 1)|(p^m-1)$. I've tried to understand why this must be true, but haven't managed to prove it. Does anyone know how to prove it? And does the result hold for more general cases than $p$ being prime, too?

It further says that from $(p^r - 1)|(p^m-1)$ it follows that $(T^{p^r}-T)|(T^{p^m}- T)$. Why's that?

Comment: There are many many proofs of this.

Comment: You could use the fact that $X-1$ divides $X^k-1$ for every integer $k\geq 1$.

Comment: @DionelJaime Yes, I've guessed so. But I haven't found one, so could you please tell me how the result is called or where to find a proof of it?

Comment: @Kapil Thanks for the hint. Could you please explain further how to use it?

Comment: @lulu Yes, thank you! This solves the first part of my question. Do you have a hint for the second part, too?

Answer (score 1):

Write $m= kr+ n$ where $0\leq n<r$ Then we have $$p^{kr}p^n \equiv 1 \pmod{p^r-1}$$
Since  $p^r \equiv 1 \pmod{p^r-1}$ we have now $$p^n \equiv 1 \pmod{p^r-1}\implies p^r-1\mid p^n-1$$

so if $n\ne 0$ then  $$p^r-1\leq p^n-1 \leq p^{r-1}-1\implies p\leq 1 $$
A contradiction, so $r\mid m$.

The other way, if $r\mid m$ then $m=kr$ so we have $$p^m-1 = (p^r)^k-1 = (p^r-1)\Big((p^r)^{k-1}+(p^r)^{k-2}+...p^r+1\Big)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain why the implications in the first four lines of it and the fact that $(2^r - 1)|(p^m - 1)$ do hold?

Comment: Typo.............

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! 
Could you please explain the second part, too, i.e., why for $(p^r - 1)|(p^m - 1)$ it follows that the polynomial $T^{p^r}-T$ divides the polynomial $T^{p^m}-T$?